# How to set a Referer on an android WebView

Tags: android, webview

Is it possible to set the `HTTP referer` or `HTTP header` data generally in a `WebView`?

I know there is a method `loadUrl(String url, Map<String, String> additionalHttpHeaders)`

[How to send a referer request in a url for a webView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342399/how-to-send-a-referer-request-in-a-url-for-a-webview)

But the headers are only sent for the given URL.
I need to set headers for every request that is sent via JavaScript from within the WebView.

I Have try to open the webapplication within mobile application..
Does somebody know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can override WebViewClient's method `shouldInterceptRequest` and edit the request on-the-fly, here is how it is done on Kotlin:

```kotlin
override fun shouldInterceptRequest(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest): WebResourceResponse? {
  val url = request.url.toString()
  request.requestHeaders.putIfAbsent("Referer", "YourReferer")
  return null //Returning null means that the WebView should continue loading
}
```

You can do the same for `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, by editing the request header map and then returning false.

Whether you should override them both, depends on your use case. If you want to send referer header for literally loading anything **inside** a website, then you should override `shouldInterceptRequest`. However, if you want to send referer header when loading a **new** website, then you should override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` (For example, when moving from page to page). I believe the first one is what you want.